# How to access private instance through docker

Tags: docker, psql

I have 2 servers in a subnet (A & B). A and B can talk to each other though private IP. I have deployed a docker on server A, now I want to access Server B from docker though private IP how can I do that?

I have database on server B, I can access database from server A but cant access from docker inside server A.

Comment: What have you tried?  What doesn't work?  Is there a specific problem you're encountering?

Comment: basically I have database on server B, I can access database on Server B from server A but cant access it from docker inside server A.

Comment: That sounds like a fairly routine setup.  Can you edit the question to include the actual error message you're getting, and some details on how you're trying to configure the container to talk to the remote database?  This isn't a question with a generic answer.

Comment: I am also able to ping server B from A but not able to ping server B from docker inside server A

Answer (score 0):

Start the container on Server B with `docker run -p <port>:<internal_port>` and that opens the port on Server B for everyone. Then connect to that container from A by accessing `<port>` through the IP of B.

Comment: basically I have database on server B and I want to access that from docker on server A. I can access that database from server A but cant access from docker inside server A.

Comment: Did you run the database container with -p<port>:<port>? Is there a firewall active on B? Can you access the database on B through that private IP address of server B, that also server A sees?

Comment: yes I have run database container with -p<port>:<port> and I can access the database on B through that private IP address of server B.

Comment: if the docker setup is clustered (sharing docker network) then the containers can talk to each other by using their container name and you don't need to map ports. if only your server setup is clustered (but not your docker setup) then you should indeed map ports with -p xx:yy. If you can access ip:port (IP of server B and port on which container is mapped) from inside server A then you should be able to do the same from inside the container on server A. If this doesn't work you can maybe check if you have overlapping IP ranges?